# can collections.filter be wrong?

Tags: java, android, collections, guava, android-guava

I try to filter a collection according to a predicate:

```
                private void filterExpiredOffers() {
                    mOffersList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(
                            mOffersList, new Predicate<Offer>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean apply(Offer offer) {
                                    return mUnlockExpirationCalculator
                                            .isUnlockValid(offer);
                                }
                            }));
                }
```

and:

```
public boolean isUnlockValid(Offer offer) {
    return ((offer.unlockExpirationDate == null) || (System
            .currentTimeMillis() < offer.unlockExpirationDate.getTime()));
}
```

I see an offer has gotten a "false" as a result

but yet, I see it in the arrayList later on.

Am I doing the filter wrong?

[image]

Comment: (Basically, the answer is: no, `Collection2.filter` cannot be wrong. The implementation is quite simple, and when iterating over the `Collection` it will only return elements for which `predicate.apply` returns `true`.)

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't do things like this:

```
public boolean isUnlockValid(Offer offer) {
    return ((offer.unlockExpirationDate == null) || (System
            .currentTimeMillis() < offer.unlockExpirationDate.getTime()));
}
```

Create a class instance instead, which captures `System.currentTimeMillis()` and uses it. This way your filter will stay stable over time.

Consider something like this

```
class UnlockValidPredicate implements Predicate<Offer> {
    public UnlockValidPredicate() {
        this(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public UnlockValidPredicate(long millis) {
        this.millis = millis;
    }

    @Overrride public boolean apply(Offer offer) {
        return offer.unlockExpirationDate == null
                || millis < offer.unlockExpirationDate.getTime();
    }

    private final long millis;
}
```

Also consider getting rid of `null`s. Setting `unlockExpirationDate` to `new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE)` is good enough for "never expire", isn't it?

> That's not it. The current time was Sep 7th. The unlockExpirationDate was Aug 30th. It's not a matter of days between the filtering and the debugging i did. what else can it be?

---

Get rid of `Date`, it's stupid *mutable* class. **Most probably, you changed it somehow.** Things like

```
 MyClass(Date date) {
     this.date = date;
 }
```

and

```
 Date getDate() {
     return date;
 }
```

are a recipe for disaster. The best solution is to use an immutable class (available in Java 8 or JodaTime). The second best is to use `long millis`. The last is to `clone` the `Date` everywhere.

Comment: That's not it. The current time was Sep 7th. The unlockExpirationDate was Aug 30th. It's not a matter of days between the filtering and the debugging i did. what else can it be?

Comment: how is `long millis` better than `Date` of a specific date?

Comment: anyhow why is my predicate returns true? (even though i couldn't catch it during debugging)

Comment: @EladBenda `millis` is immutable. Unless you somehow do `millis = ...`. it won't change. Doing `Date now = new Date(); MyClass = new MyClass(now); now.set(....);` or similar blows and that's my guess of what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

What seems most likely is that the predicate was true when you did the filtering, and then the predicate became false later -- which seems perfectly possible when you're using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: That's not it. The current time was Sep 7th. The unlockExpirationDate was Aug 30th. It's not a matter of days between the filtering and the debugging i did. what else can it be?